# In my app, manifest file i have defined the application to support all devices (both mobile and tablet). But some mobiles are not supported?

Tags: android

In Play store xolo mobile comes under supported devices category. But while searching in xolo mobile, my app is incompatabile..??I have included my manifest file also.

Is there any thing i missed in manifest file???

```
android:versionCode="2"
android:versionName="1.1" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17"
     />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<supports-screens android:smallScreens="true"
                  android:normalScreens="true"
                  android:largeScreens="true"
                  android:xlargeScreens="true"
                  android:anyDensity="true"
                  android:resizeable="true"
                  android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="240"
                  />
<compatible-screens>

    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />


    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

   <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />



</compatible-screens>
```

Comment: android:minSdkVersion="8"

Comment: my app supports min 11 version. Even 15 version mobile is not supported for my app.

Comment: Can you post your Xolo mobile details ?

Comment: what error u get while opening in xolo mobiles

Comment: in xolo mobile my app is incompatible. I cant even download app in that mobile.

Comment: xolo A500S,... this mobile is under the supported devices on the play store for my app. but i cant download the app through mobile.

Comment: @Divya: why are you using `<compatible-screens>` manifest tag? Do you have any specific requirement ?

Comment: NO..my app should support all devices with specified version...so only  i included <compatible screen>..

Comment: @Spring Breaker: Now i have reset preference in settings.so now i can download my app on xolo..But any how there are some unsupported devices for my app in play store...how to make all devices to support ???Any idea????

Answer (score 0):

Change like this.

```
<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="8"
android:targetSdkVersion="19"
 />
```

Answer (score 0):

You have defined:

```
android:minSdkVersion="11"
```

There are still a lot devices on Android 2.2 and 2.3 version. Change it to lower. I would suggest 8.

Answer (score 0):

reduce the min sdk version to 8 and target to 19. Then most of the devices will be covered

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19"
     />
```